# Vue router not working with laravel email verify url 405 error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, vuejs3

I am building a Laravel SPA with Vue, but I ran into an issue with the routing. I will get an 405 error when trying to post the data.

**The verify url**

```
....com/email/verify/16/0f91b48f3517e34d1cc548579d29959e8799b43b?expires=1621163245&signature=3f1d4076b8ee5e3d249893bf15b895d4d2b51d832522e6124c8e4a0a1beed225
```

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::post('email/verify/{user}/{hash}', [VerificationController::class, 'verify']);
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
   return view('layouts.vue');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

**router.js**

```
{ path: '/email/verify/:id/:hash', name: 'verification.verify', component: Verify }
```

Seeing that it will throw an 405 error code which is the result of `$request->hasValidSignature()`

Comment: You can't bind server side routing to vue js use 'Vue Router'

Comment: Iets an API route not an web route 

Comment: you can call api route with fetch API aur axios not like this.

Comment: Please novice that the post route is api/email/verify

Comment: Can you share a link to a repo that reproduces the problem?